# Cassandra timeout during read query

Tags: cassandra, timeout, cassandra-2.0

Cassandra read timeout excpetion is happening for a table that has 5.5 million records on a SELECT query.

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra
>   timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were
>   required but only 0 replica responded)    at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:88)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy(ReadTimeoutException.java:25)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
>     at
>   com.batchjob.util.DataUtil.getFaIdClientIdKeysDataList(DataUtil.java:50)

We are trying to retrive based on a CURRENT_DATE column as shown below in the query

```
Statement stmt = QueryBuilder.select().column("FA_ID").column("CLIENT_ID").from(tableName).allowFiltering().where(lt("CURRENT_DATE",localDate)).setFetchSize(5);
ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);
```

**cassandra.yaml** file configuration:

```
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 360000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 360000
request_timeout_in_ms: 360000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 600000
```

Also we have `gc_grace_seconds = 86400(1 DAY)` for the specified tables as we have a DELETE job to remove the tombstones.

Any solution in identifying the issue would help us a lot!

---

Basically the issue happens only with the below tables where the number of records are in millions.
**NOTE** - This READ Timeout issue has a specific pattern - usually it is happening every Monday. Not hapenning on other days of the week from Tuesday through Sunday.Batch job runs daily on regular basis.

5.6 million(Table X)
3.7 million(Table Y)
Code snippet for fetching the records:

```
public List<DataDeleteObject> getFaIdClientIdKeysDataList(String tableName) {
    List<DataDeleteObject> dataDeleteObjList = new ArrayList<DataDeleteObject>();
    Statement stmt = QueryBuilder.select().column(CommonConstantInterface.FA_ID)
            .column(CommonConstantInterface.CLIENT_ID).from(tableName)
            .allowFiltering().where(lt(CommonConstantInterface.CURRENT_DATE, getCurrentDate()))
            .setFetchSize(5);

    ResultSet rs = config.getSession().execute(stmt);
    DataDeleteObject fgaDO = null;
    int count = 0;
    while (!rs.isExhausted()) {
        count++;
        Row row = rs.one();
        fgaDO = new DataDeleteObject();
        fgaDO.setFaId(row.getString(CommonConstantInterface.FA_ID));
        fgaDO.setClientId(row.getVarint(CommonConstantInterface.CLIENT_ID));
        dataDeleteObjList.add(fgaDO);
    }
    return dataDeleteObjList;
}
```

The below is the Data Model. Currently we don't have any index maintained on any columns in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE X (fa_id text, client_id varint, client_first_name text, client_last_name text, current_date date, data_as_of_date date, has_fga boolean, segment text, PRIMARY KEY (fa_id, client_id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (client_id ASC) AND gc_grace_seconds = 86400;

CREATE TABLE Y (fa_id text, client_id varint, client_first_name text, client_last_name text, current_date date, data_as_of_date date, has_mtp boolean, segmentation text, PRIMARY KEY (fa_id, client_id)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (client_id ASC) AND gc_grace_seconds = 86400;
```

Comment: Your code and the expected behavior would help us a lot!

Comment: I'll suggest, without seeing your data model, that `ALLOW FILTERING` is killing your query. Check out [this doc](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2) and others.

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: We were trying to analyze and find a pattern for this READ timeout issue . I have updated my post with data model and code snippet used for this. Please suggest if index on client_id would help here?

Comment: Sorry I meant index on  current_date column would it help? The select query is supposed to fetch few records(1000 to 5000 max) out of 5.6 million records.